# Float values in strings PHP

Tags: php

I have a html form (it is a receipt form for a shop) which contains around a hundred text boxes and the user is suppose to enter a **float value** or something of the form of **"20.2*33.4"**. The form is submitted to a php page. I want to make sure that every text box contains same pattern and then I want to evaluate the multiplication that is inside the text to.

I want to know how to check if the string is in the format "float*float"?

Can any please help. Thank You

Comment: What kind of help? What have you tried?

Comment: You are building software and your users are still using equations.

Comment: how about: Box (operator selector) Box. or explode on the * multiple the resulting 2 vars.

Comment: I have tried using eval but learned that using it is risky as it executes the string so will it be good idea to make sure that the string is in the stated format?

what will be the best idea to check if the string is in that format?

Answer (score 1):

You can use a regex to check the format, then parse out the numbers and the operator, then do the calculation.

```
$total = 0;
$string = '20.2*33.4';
if(preg_match('/^(\d*\.?\d+)(?:\*)(\d*\.?\d+)$/', $string, $matches) === 1){
    $total = floatval($matches[1]) * floatval($matches[2]);
}
```

DEMO: http://ideone.com/azhMag

Answer (score -2):

This is not possible, the only function you can use is eval but it's very dangerous used like that in a form.

If you want to evaluate an expression, then you need to create your own language (with parser, lexer etc..).

So it's impossible. You can look here http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shunting-yard_algorithm

Edit : if it's only a simple multiplication with always two parts you can just explode it as commented above.

Comment: its possible, explode on the * multiple the 2 vars

Comment: You give multiple solutions to the problem, yet say it's impossible... ?

Comment: Actually I find it does provide an answer, the link just provides more details about it.